# Update EventBusSubscriber Trigger Status

Tags: apex, platform-event, subscriber

I am creating on the fly using apex a `PlatformEventSubscriberConfig` based on a specific user that is selected from a drop-down with multiple users.

- for that I'm using the rest api, the creation of the component is not a problem and is working properly,
- but at the time when the trigger is executed, it runs with the automated salesforce user until the subscriber is suspended and resumed.
- Once it is resumed again, it runs with the corresponding user. From here the question, is it possible to modify the state of the subscriber so that from apex it can be suspended and resumed without a user having to do it manually?

I already review the `EventBusSubscriber` but is read-only, so cannot be updated from there, also, I was tried creating it, and then with a `PATCH` update the user just to see if it's works and that was not happen.

Any suggestion?

Comment: I'm surprised you need to suspend/resume - at least when I deploy changes in this metadata, it takes (although you have to wait a while)